# React + Ionic 5: Tab navigation problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm having trouble to get tabs navigation working properly.

This is my code so far:

App.tsx:

```
const App: React.FC = () =>
  <IonApp>
      <IonReactRouter>
          <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
              <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/home"/>}/>
              <Route path="/home" render={(props) => <Home {...props}/>} exact={true}/>
          </IonRouterOutlet>
      </IonReactRouter>
  </IonApp>
)
```

Home.tsx:

```
const Home: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = (props: RouteComponentProps) => (
    <IonPage>
        <IonTabs>
            <IonRouterOutlet id='tabs'>
                <Route path='/:tab(myDecks)' render={(props) => <MyDecks {...props} />} exact/>
                <Route path='/:tab(explore)' render={(props) => <Explore {...props} />} exact/>
                <Redirect from='/home' to='/myDecks'/>
            </IonRouterOutlet>
            <IonTabBar slot='bottom'>
                <IonTabButton tab='myDecks' href='/myDecks'>
                    <IonLabel>My Decks</IonLabel>
                </IonTabButton>
                <IonTabButton tab='explore' href='/explore'>
                    <IonLabel>Explore</IonLabel>
                </IonTabButton>
            </IonTabBar>
        </IonTabs>
    </IonPage>
);
```

MyDecks.tsx:

```
const MyDecks: React.FunctionComponent<RouteComponentProps> = (props: RouteComponentProps) => {
    return <>
            <IonHeader>
                <IonToolbar>
                    <IonTitle>My Decks</IonTitle>
                </IonToolbar>
            </IonHeader>

            <IonContent className='ion-padding'>
                My Decks
            </IonContent>
    </>
};
```

The current behavior is:

1. User access /
2. User is redirected to /home
3. Another redirect to /myDeck, "My Deck" tab selected and URL is good.
4. If the user clicks on the "Explore" tab, URL changes, "My Deck" tab is deselected and the "Explore" tab is selected, however, the page content doesn't change.

If I alter the order of the routes inside `<IonRouterOutlet>`, then the "My Decks" tab is originally selected, and when the user first clicks the "Explore" tab, it renders ok, but never get back to "My Decks" tab.

I also noticed that when refreshing at /myDeck or /explore no content renders at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[According to the React Tabs starter template](https://github.com/ionic-team/starters/blob/master/react/official/tabs/src/App.tsx) you have to nest the `IonRouterOutlet` inside of `IonTabs`, which is nested in `IonReactRouter`.

Here's how their App.tsx looks like:

```
  <IonApp>
    <IonReactRouter>
      <IonTabs>
        <IonRouterOutlet>
          <Route path="/tab1" component={Tab1} exact={true} />
          <Route path="/tab2" component={Tab2} exact={true} />
          <Route path="/tab3" component={Tab3} />
          <Route path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/tab1" />} exact={true} />
        </IonRouterOutlet>
        <IonTabBar slot="bottom">
          <IonTabButton tab="tab1" href="/tab1">
            <IonIcon icon={triangle} />
            <IonLabel>Tab 1</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>
          <IonTabButton tab="tab2" href="/tab2">
            <IonIcon icon={ellipse} />
            <IonLabel>Tab 2</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>
          <IonTabButton tab="tab3" href="/tab3">
            <IonIcon icon={square} />
            <IonLabel>Tab 3</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>
        </IonTabBar>
      </IonTabs>
    </IonReactRouter>
  </IonApp>
```

For me it worked that way. Anyway Ionic+React documentation is not very detailed regarding things like that. One still has to search very much.

Comment: Everything looks good. "IonReactRouter" is an additional package that can be imported from "@ionic/react-router". This will avoid reload of the page when you switch the tabs

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to wrap the tabs content with `<IonPage>`.

```
const MyDecks: React.FunctionComponent<RouteComponentProps> = (props: RouteComponentProps) => {
    return <IonPage>
            <IonHeader>
                <IonToolbar>
                    <IonTitle>My Decks</IonTitle>
                </IonToolbar>
            </IonHeader>

            <IonContent className='ion-padding'>
                My Decks
            </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
};
```

Comment: correct, page components are the components that take visibility classes from the ionic router in order to display content.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <IonApp>
  <IonPage>
    <IonReactRouter>
      <Menu />
      <IonTabs>
        <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
          <Route path="/Login" exact={true}>
            <Login />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/" exact={true}>
            <Redirect to="/Login"></Redirect>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/settings" exact={true}>
            <UserSettings />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/page/:name" exact={true}>
            <Page />
          </Route>
        </IonRouterOutlet>

        <IonTabBar slot="bottom">
          <IonTabButton tab="home" href="/page/Inbox">
            <IonLabel>Home</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>
          <IonTabButton tab="settings" href="/settings">
            <IonLabel>Settings</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>
        </IonTabBar>
        
      </IonTabs>
    </IonReactRouter>
  </IonPage>
</IonApp>
```

Comment: Hello Abap, could you please add details on how this is solving OP's problems ?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.